# Individual toggles inside an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some content coming in which I am running through a repeat, each one of these content items has to have a toggle open/close functionality to it. I figured my best bet in marking them individually is using something like the $index of the item in the repeat. I am just using a (bootstrap) class to show/hide like so :

```
     <a ng-click="{{$index}}inner = !{{$index}}inner" >{{item.node.id}}</a>
     <div class="nested " ng-class="{'collapse' : !{{$index}}inner">
```

So - a click toggle on the a above. This does not work because of the syntax, but what I'm wondering here is if there is a nice elegant solution to this problem. This way I tried first seems a little messy. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ng-repeat directive created a scope for each of the elements. Therefore you could just use the `ng-click` to toggle a property on that scope.

Also the syntax of your `ng-class` is not totally correct.

For working example see http://jsbin.com/yuyucojeco/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2):

I like adding properties to the actual objects themselves.  Then, within your `ng-repeat`, you can just reference the individual object (instead of trying to re-index into the array) and apply all logic as you need.

Maybe something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array">
 <a ng-click="item.collapsed = !item.collapsed" >{{item.node.id}}</a>
 <div class="nested " ng-class="{'collapse' : item.collapsed"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: perfect answer. @ryanyuyu

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented smt similar inside an ng-repeat using bootstrap as well like so:
here is the button:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{item.id}}" class="accordion-toggle btn btn-xs btn-success"></a>
```

then the collapsible tab:

```
<div class="accordion-body collapse" id="{{item.id}}"> <!-- accordion starts -->
    <!-- some content here -->  
</div> <!-- accordion ends -->
```